# iconos que bajan con scroll hasta un punto determinado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

tengo unos iconos los cuales se bajan cuando hago scroll, pero necesito que se paren antes de llegar al footer, ya que actualmente bajan hasta el final de la ventana y se moontan en el footer

HTML

```
    <head>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js "></script>
        <script src="owl_carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="owl_carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/airNostrum.js "></script>


        <!-- Todos los plugins JavaScript de Bootstrap (también puedes
             incluir archivos JavaScript individuales de los únicos
             plugins que utilices) -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
        <script src="js/menu/menu.js "></script>

        <script src="js/dropdown/dropdown.js "></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>.....</header>
<div class="container pad_top_12">

            <h1 class="arran col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s</h1>


            <div class="row flex-nowrap ">

                <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">
                    <p class="fecha_not text-left mr-2">08 FEB 2018</p>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md  col-sm-6 col-xs-6  icon-tab-mov ">
                    <img src="iconos/ic_download.svg" alt="" class="img-dow opac7">
                    <img src="iconos/ic_printer.svg" alt="" class="img-print">
                    <img src="iconos/share_ic.svg" alt="" class="img-share">

                </div>



                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <p class="fecha_not ml-2">08 FEB 2018</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pad-top-av"><img src="img/iberia_avion.png" alt="" class="img-viaj"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <p class="desc-av ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            </div>
        <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-md-2  bar_lat1 " id="scroll-not">
                        <p><img src="iconos/share_ic.svg" alt=""></p>
                        <p><img src="iconos/ic_printer.svg" alt=""></p>
                        <p><img src="iconos/ic_download.svg" alt="" class="opac7"></p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 "></div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 ">
                        <h3 class="not-tit">“Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s”</h3>
                        <p class="tex-not">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
                            versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                        <p class="tex-not">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
                            more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                        <img src="img/sag_fam_det.png" alt="" class="sag-fam img-viaj">
                        <p class="desc-av1 ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        <p class="tex-not">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
                            versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                        <p class="tex-not">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
                            more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                        <p class="txt-p"><img src="iconos/etiqueta.svg" alt=""><span>  aviones,rutas,ofertas</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 "></div>
                </div>
        <footer>...</footer>
    </body>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $(function() {

            $(document).on('scroll', function() {

                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
                    $('#scroll-not').addClass('show');
                } else {
                    $('#scroll-not').removeClass('show');
                }
            });

            $('#scroll-not').on('click', scrollToTop);
            $('#scroll-not').css('background', 'transparent');
        });

        function scrollToTop() {
            verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
            element = $('body');
            offset = element.offset();
            offsetTop = offset.top;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: offsetTop
            }, 500, 'linear');
        }

    });
```

CSS

```
.col-cab {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #f7f6f4);
    min-width: 100%;
}

.col-cab1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #db0829, #a80e20);
    min-width: 100%;
}

.top-cabecera {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}

.borde-desplegable1 {
    border-top: 3px red solid !important;
}

.pos-submenu-index {
    float: right;
    right: 25%;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2 {
    /* Size and position */
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    /* Styles */
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 1000000;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -3px;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000 transparent;
    z-index: 1000000;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown {
    /* Size & position */
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /* Styles */
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    font-weight: normal;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    list-style: none;
    /* Hiding */
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e8ea;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li i {
    float: right;
    color: inherit;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li:first-of-type a {
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li:last-of-type a {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
}


/* Hover state */

.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li:hover a {
    background: #f3f8f8;
}


/* Active state */

.wrapper-dropdown-2.active .dropdown {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}


/* No CSS3 support */

.no-opacity .wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown,
.no-pointerevents .wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown {
    display: none;
    opacity: 1;
    /* If opacity support but no pointer-events support */
    pointer-events: auto;
    /* If pointer-events support but no pointer-events support */
}

.no-opacity .wrapper-dropdown-2.active .dropdown,
.no-pointerevents .wrapper-dropdown-3.active .dropdown {
    display: block;
}


/*#############################*/

.posicionamiento_top {
    width: 70%;
    left: 15%;
}

.marg1em {
    padding: 2em 1em;
}

.rojo_bot {
    border-bottom: 3px red solid;
}

.bor_bot {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
}

.not {
    font-family: IberiaHeadline;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.13;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    color: #0c1332;
}

.eleg {
    font-family: IberiaText;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #4a4a4a;
    border: 1px solid rgba(151, 151, 151, 0.35);
}

.fecha_not {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #000000;
}

.txt-az {
    font-family: IberiaHeadline;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: -0.4px;
    color: #0090d0;
}

.txt-peq {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.69;
    letter-spacing: -0.2px;
    color: #333333;
}

.gif_not {
    text-align: center;
}

.foot-gr {
    background-color: #f7f6f4;
    padding: 50px 15px;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.not-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.back-wh {}

.centrar_car {
    border: 1px solid red;
}


/*****.back-wh{

   padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    width: 25%;
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;;
}
.centrar_car{
     display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-align-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: distribute;
    align-content: space-around;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;

}**/

.foot-gr .cent-bot {
    margin: auto;
}

.tam-cont {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
}

.copiright {
    background-color: #dfe7ef;
    padding-top: 3em;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 2;
    letter-spacing: 0.1px;
    color: #0c1332;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.copi-sig {
    text-align: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:450px) {
    .cop_resp {
        display: none;
    }
    .cop_resp1 {
        display: block;
    }
    .cop-air {
        padding-top: 1em;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:449px) {
    .cop_resp1 {
        display: none;
    }
}

.ico-rs {
    padding: 0 4%
}

.pr-1 {
    padding-right: 1em
}

.copiright {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: IberiaText;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 2;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
    color: #0c1332;
}


/****************carrusel************/

.foot-gr .thumb-smar {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.multi-carousel {
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

.multi-carousel .carousel-control-next,
.multi-carousel .carousel-control-prev {
    width: 25px;
    background: gray;
}

.item {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    border: solid 1px #dbdbdb;
}

.owl-carousel .nav-btn {
    height: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 26px;
    cursor: pointer;
    bottom: 42%;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-prev.disabled,
.owl-carousel .owl-next.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.owl-carousel .prev-slide {
    background-image: url(../img/flecha-air-izq.png);
    left: -1%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.owl-carousel .next-slide {
    background-image: url(../img/flecha_air.png);
    right: -1%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.border_pr {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.not_az {
    font-family: IberiaText;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 3.08;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #0090d0;
}

.fl-not {
    color: #6d6f7b;
}

.arran {
    font-family: IberiaHeadline;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #6d6f7b;
}

.desc-av {
    font-family: IberiaText;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.57;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #9b9b9b;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 4em;
}

.desc-av1 {
    font-family: IberiaText;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.57;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #9b9b9b;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 4em;
}



@media only screen and (max-width:1366px) {
    .item {
        width: 70%;
    }
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.pad_top {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
.pad_top_mant{
    padding-top: 12em
}

.pad_top_12 {
    padding-top: 12em;
}
.pad_top_12_res{
      padding-top: 12em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:880px){
.pad_top {
    padding-top: 2em;
}

}
@media only screen and (max-width:990px) {
   .pad_top_12 {
    padding-top: 6em;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width:1366px) {
      .pad_top_12_res {
    padding-top: 6em;
}
}
.pad_top1 {
    padding-top: 3em;
}

.pad-top-av {
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.not-tit {
    font-family: IberiaHeadline;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #4a4a4a;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.tex-not {
    font-family: IberiaText;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.56;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: justify;
    color: #33333a;
}

.mar-l-2 {
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-top: -2em;
}

.txt-p {
    font-family: IberiaText;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.57;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #0090d0;
    padding-top: 2em;
}

.txt-p img {
    padding-right: 2%;
}

.img-share {
    padding-right: 1em;
    border-right: 1px solid #979797;
}

.img-dow {
    border-left: 1px solid #979797;
    margin-left: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
}

.opac7 {
    opacity: 0.7
}

.img-print {
    padding-left: 1em;
}

.bar_lat {
    position: fixed;
    top: 70%;
    right: 70%;
    border-right: solid 1px #979797;
    width: 80px;
    z-index: 10;
}


/*.bar_lat1{

    position: fixed;
    top: 98%;
 right: 75%;
    border-right: solid 1px #979797;
    width: 80px;


}*/

#scroll-not:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1367px) {
    .icon-tab-mov img {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:991px) {
    .bar_lat1 {
        display: none;
    }
    .fecha_not {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .icon-tab-mov1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        padding-right: 3em;
    }
    .icon-tab-mov {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        padding-right: 3em;
    }
    .mar-l-2 .sag-fam {
        display: block;
        margin: auto
    }
    .mar-l-2 {
        margin: auto;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:990px) and (min-width:669px) {
    .arran {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .not_az {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    .icon-tab-mov img {
        width: 32px;
    }
    .not-tit {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:668px) {
    .arran {
        font-size: 28px;
    }
    .not_az {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    .icon-tab-mov img {
        width: 29px;
    }
    .not-tit {
        font-family: IberiaHeadline;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        line-height: 1.39;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        color: #4a4a4a;
    }
    .tex-not {
        font-family: IberiaText;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        line-height: 1.56;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-align: justify;
        color: #4a4a4a;
    }
    .desc-av1 {
        padding-bottom: 2em;
    }
}

.cab-gris {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #f7f6f4);
}

.not-desp {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.img-resp {
    height: 100%;
}

.active .pad-rojo {
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

.img-viaj {
    width: 100%
}

@media only screen and (max-width:992px) {
    .pad-top-av {
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }
}

.ml-2 {
    margin-left: 2em;
}

.pl-2 {
    padding-left: 2em;
}

.pr-2 {
    padding-right: 2em;
}

.pad_top_med {
    padding-top: 15px
}

#scroll-not {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 1px solid #979797;
    z-index: 99999999;
    width: 55px;
    color: #eeeeee;
    line-height: 48px;
    bottom: 25px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1698px) and (min-width:1429px) {
    #scroll-not {
        right: 80%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1430px) and (min-width:992px) {
    #scroll-not {
        right: 85%;
    }
    .top-cabecera {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10000000;
        width: 92%;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        height: 60px;
        left: 0;
    }
}

#scroll-not:hover {
    background-color: #888888;
}

#scroll-not.show {
    visibility: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:991px) {
    #scroll-not {
        display: none!important;
    }
}



.peg_abajo {

}

@media (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px) {
    .pos-lupa {
        position: relative;
        left: 65%;
        width: 51%;
    }
    .pos-logo {
        position: relative;
        left: 8%;
    }
    .lupa {
        margin-top: -56px;
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
    .top-cabecera {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10000000;
        width: 85%;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        height: 75px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    .pos-enlaces-form {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 17px;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 50%;
        width: 350px;
    }
    .pos-logo {
        position: relative;
        left: 5%;
        /* width: 45%; */
    }
}

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-cab {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #f7f6f4);
        max-width: 100%;
        min-width: 0;
    }
    .pos-enlaces-form {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 17px;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 50%;
        width: 350px;
    }
    .pos-logo {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        width: 70%;
    }
    .posicionamiento_top {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    .top-cabecera-multimedia {
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 89% !important;
    }
    .pos-enlaces-form {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: -5px;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 50%;
        width: 90%;
    }
    .lupa {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: -25px;
        margin-left: 65%;
    }
}
.pt-1{
    padding-top: 1em;
}
/**********home*****************/
#video-viewport { position: absolute; top: -10px; left: 0; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; }
video { display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

cómo puedo hacer para que se paren los icomos de "share, print y download" cuando lleguen al footer.

Muchas gracias, un saludo

Comment: puedes poner el css y los script de js que pones en el header, como para reproducir el ejemplo completo?

Comment: es esto lo que necesitas? o necesitas algo más?, te he puesto los css de la ventana y las llamadas a los scripts

Comment: acabo de ver que en los CSS el `#scroll-not` tiene un `bottom:25px` el cual hace que aparezcan dichos iconos al lado del texto, si quito el bottom, los iconos aparecen más arriba (encima de una imagen) y cuando finaliza el scroll los iconos están correctamente alineados, no sé si hay algún modo de controlar ese `bottom:25px` del id `#scroll-not`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no sé si hay algún modo de controlar ese bottom:25px del id #scroll-not

Respecto a eso en particular, tú eres libre de cambiar el estilo añadiendo tu propia hoja de estilos después de todos los otros CSS y poner, por ejemplo

```
#scroll-not {
  bottom: 55px;
}
```

O darle una posición referente al tope del documento, o decirle que siempre se mantenga en medio.

El punto es que no puedes saber a priori la altura del header o del footer, de manera que que ponerle una posición fija que se muestre o esconda **depende de la altura del contenedor flotante** y en este caso la posición del footer.

En tu caso, el contenedor flotante tiene su borde superior a una distancia del inicio del documento determinado por

```
var offetSuperior = $('#scroll-not').offset().top;
```

Y una altura determinada por

```
var altura = $('#scroll-not').outerHeight();
```

Por lo cual la distancia de su borde inferior al tope del documento es la suma del offset Superior y la altura.

```
var offsetInferior = $('#scroll-not').offset().top + $('#scroll-not').outerHeight();
```

Ya que el contenedor flotante tiene una posición fija, esa variable va cambiando a medida que haces scroll sobre el documento.

A su vez, el borde superior del footer está a una distancia del borde superior del documento dada por:

```
var posicionFooter = $('footer').offset.top();
```

Ilustrándolo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La superposición que estás experimentando ocurre **cuando el borde inferior del contenedor flotante está por encima del footer**. Entonces, para prevenir esa circunstancia, la comprobación que debieras hacer es:

```
var offsetInferior = $('#scroll-not').offset().top + $('#scroll-not').outerHeight(),
    posicionFooter = $('footer').offset.top(),
    superPuestos = offsetInferior > posicionFooter;
```

Entonces, cuando defines si mostrar u ocultar el contenedor flotante, añade esa comprobación.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {

    var offsetInferior = $('#scroll-not').offset().top + $('#scroll-not').outerHeight(),
        posicionFooter = $('footer').offset.top(),
        superPuestos = offsetInferior > posicionFooter;

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 && !superPuestos) {
        $('#scroll-not').addClass('show');
    } else {
        $('#scroll-not').removeClass('show');
    }
});
```

En otras palabras, sólo muestras el flotante si el scroll es mayor a 100 Y no tapa el footer.

En casos de borde debieras hacer lo mismo con el header (ventanas de muy poca altura y headers muy extensos, por ejemplo)

Comment: estoy intentando hacer lo que me comentas, pero al poner esas variables, ya no se me muestran los iconos, no sé si tb tengo que hacer algo más en la función `function scrollToTop() {}` que puse en el js.

Comment: usa la consola para ver qué valor están tomando las variables. La función `scrollToTop` sólo aplica cuando pinchas uno de los botones